# Trying to save notes for each day of a calendar year android studio

Tags: java, android

I don't get any errors but this doesn't work every time I try to change date in the calendar my app stops working and even when I press the save button it also keeps stop working before I add the code with the array it was working properly

public class Calendar extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private CalendarView calendarView;
private TextView currentDate;
private Button btnsavenote;
private EditText newNote, showNote;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);
    calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calen_v);
    currentDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentDate);
    btnsavenote = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_note);
    newNote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newNote);
    showNote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shownote);
    final String [][] array = new String[31][12];



    calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        String tDate = (dayOfMonth) + "/" + month + "/" + year;
        currentDate.setText(tDate);
        }
    });

    btnsavenote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        String MytextMessage = newNote.getText().toString();
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int a;
            int b;
            a = Integer.parseInt(array [30][2]);
            b = Integer.parseInt(array [31][2]);
            array[a][b] = MytextMessage;
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: array[31][2] in the onClick method will cause an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. You defined the first dimension of your array as 31, so the largest index you can use is 30.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir i fixed this but my notes dont appear...any idea on this ?

Comment: Put the following line into the "onClick" method should solve your problem: String MytextMessage = newNote.getText().toString();

Comment: Oh sorry i am new at this thanks a lot it worked!